# Formatting Multiple Columns - Specific Range to last row - Application defined error

Tags: excel, vba, format, range

I thought application /object defined referred to an reference not being found?

I specified the location of the range i need formatted but am still getting the error?

Any expect have an idea?

```
Dim lastrow As Long


lastrow = Sheets("comparison report").Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
 With Sheets("comparison report")
   .Range("G3:G" & lastrow & ",H3:H" & lastrow & ",I3:I:G" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$€-de-DE];[Red]-#,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]"
End With
```

Comment: typo: `I3:I:G"` remove the `:G`

Comment: didn't see the forest for the trees !! much appreciated Scott !!

Comment: And really it only needs to be: `.Range("G3:I" & lastrow).Nu...`